# Send and receive message from amqp channel using IBM Integration bus

Tags: ibm-mq, amqp, ibm-integration-bus

I'm newbie on IBM products, and I would like to know what would be the best approach to achieve the following integration solution:

1. A third party application that uses only AMQP to exchange messages, will put a message on an inbound queue (managed by IBM MQ)
2. IBM integration bus(version 10) flow will retrieve that message
3. Parse the message and invoke a rest api, get a response.
4. Parse the response, and send it back to the output queue so the third party can consume it.

My MQ colleague (amqp in new for him) created the corresponding "AMQP queue manager; channel and topic" using IBM MQ 9.0.4, and provided me of the connection info.

In my understanding I thought about creating a flow that will use "MQInput node" that will connect to the queue used by the third party to drop the message, and continue my processing.

Unfortunately I’m not able to connect to that AMQP channel, neither using: The "MQInput node" on IIB v10 Nor using "MQ explorer"

I strongly believe I miss something in that integration solution: either on the mq side or on the iib side, but not able to know what.

The challenge is to know, in order to achieve the above scenario, does the component IBM MQ and IBM Integration bus are enough, or I'll some other components?

Any documentation or tutorial that could describe/explain such scenario?

Comment: Does the request message and in turn the response message have a lifetime?  For example does the third party app expect a response back in 30 seconds and if it does not receive it in 30 seconds then don't send a response?  Is IIB connecting in binding mode to a local queue manager?  If it is, is the queue manager that the third party app connects to with AMQP the same queue manager that IIB connect to?

Comment: Hi JoshMc. Basically, if the third party does not receive a response within a specific amount of time, he'll try send again the request. The third party has a setup that he'll try send X times if no response, then he'll generate an exception on his side. Regarding the IIB connection to MQ, I googled to understand what you mean by "Is IIB connecting in binding mode to a local queue manager", so I can tell you that the queue manager and the IIb are on different hosts. The IIb uses a broker installed locally on my machine(windows 7), and the queue manager(MQ 9.0.4) is on  a linux server.

Comment: On the MQ side, the third party application uses the same queue setup (queue manager, channel, queue name) as does the IIB, the only thing different is the port number. Does that answer your questions? thanks a lot

Comment: Which version of IIB are you using?  One thing to note is AMQP clients publish to Topics not queues.  The "MQInput node" cat read from a queue or a topic.

Comment: In the simplest case you can just connect via client connection to a SVRCONN channel on the queue manager and subscribe to the topic.  You would then publish your response to a topic that the AMQP client is subscribed too.

Comment: Hi JoshMc, we use IIB V10.0.0.11, and MQ 9.0.4. We'll try as you said to create a queue that will subscribe to AMQP topic, and let you know the outcome. Thanks  a lot for your help.

Comment: Hi Khilou, I'm stating that with the "MQInput node" you could "subscribe" directly to the topic.

Comment: Another option is to create a queue and make a MQ admin subscription to that topic and then have the "MQInput node" read the queue.